# Java resultset column-wise output for JSON

Tags: java, json, database, resultset

I have a

```
ResultSet rs = sql.getData(con, query);
```

with two columns and several rows. I want to get the data as a output in a JSON style output like:

```
x: [1, 2, 3, 4],

y: [2.37, 2.16, 4.82, 1.73],
```

So, I want first the data of column1 written to the first line "x" and then the second column2 to y.

All documentation I find about iterating the data of a resultset is row-wise like for the HTML table output like

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        out.append("<tr>");
        for (int col = 1; col < rsMeta.getColumnCount() + 1; col++) {
            out.append("<td>");
            out.append(rs.getString(col));
            out.append("</td>");
        }
        out.append("</tr>");
        cnt++;
    }
```

Comment: How about you try to write some code for JSON creation first?

Comment: You're talking about JSON but in your code you create XML (in a very naive manner). Do you want XML or JSON? For both you should use a library instead of creating the output format as text.

Comment: I do not want to create a JSON object in Java I just want to output it for a webapp in a JSON way. I already tried the library json-simple but could not make it output the way I wanted.

Comment: Use two lists, one for each column. Iterate through the records and store the values for each column to the appropriate list. At the end create the output by iterating over each list one after another. This works only for small datasets, because you have to store the whole data in memory.

Comment: These libraries are exactly made for the purpose to create output in JSON or XML format. Because doing it by hand is error prone. You have to consider all special cases, escaping, etc. And sorry, but looking at your code, you seem to be even unaware about the difference between XML and JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the `ResultSet` exactly once, but since you want the values by column, not by row, you need to store them in `List` objects.

Something like this:

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> y = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    x.add(rs.getInt(1));
    y.add(rs.getDouble(2));
}
System.out.println("x: " + x + ",");
System.out.println("y: " + y + ",");
```